# Using method from super class returns undefined after result

Tags: javascript

I am playing around with classes and I noticed that after checking status I am seeing the console log, but afterward I am seeing `undefined`. Can anyone explain how to get around this and why is this happening?

```js
class Test {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  status() {
    console.log("test")
  }
}

class Test1 extends Test {
      constructor(name) {
        super(name);
  }
    checkStatus() {
        super.status();
    }
}

const b = new Test1("Test")
console.log(b.checkStatus())
```

Comment: `b.checkStatus()` returns `undefined` (no returns statement is the same as `return undefined` ... which you console.log for some reason

Comment: It is because you forgot to pass the `arguments` to `super` inside the second class constructor

Comment: @AdnaneAr thats not the issue, I've checked it

Comment: interesting you address the second comment, which is complete useless, and ignore the first comment, which has your answer .... the issue is that you console.log the return value of a function that doesn't return a value, which is `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What does Console.log do?

The method `console.log` does not return a value.  This seems to be a common misunderstanding, people seem to assume that it will return what is printed to the log.

However, even if that was an assumption, `status()` does not have an explicit return, so the value is `undefined`.

### Functions vs arrow functions

Here another misunderstanding creeps in, which is the difference between regular functions and arrow functions.  Arrow functions have a convenience which is that if the function body resolves to a value, its taken as the return value.  Consider:

```js
function foo() {
  return 'foo'
}

console.log(foo())   // foo() returns 'foo', so the log shows 'foo'

const bar = () => 'bar'

console.log(bar())   // bar() returns 'bar', so the log shows 'bar'

const baz = () => console.log('baz')

console.log(baz())   // baz() returns undefined, so the log shows 'baz' and 'undefined'
```

### Use of `super`

```
checkStatus() {
   super.status();
}
```

You use `super` here for no (good) reason.  `status()` has been inherited from `class Test`, and can be called with `this.status()`.  You would only need to use `super.status()` if you were providing an override in `Test1` and needing to call the parent class implementation.

I suspect that this is actually what you intended, but because of the lack of `return` statements, you were trying to understand what was being called where and got sidetracked.

### Revised Code

Here I've renamed the classes to make things a little clearer.

`TestBase` provides our base class functionality.

`TestOverride` provides an override implementation of `status` that prepends its own name to the value returned by `TestBase.status`, called via `super` (`this.super()` here would create an infinite loop).

`TestNoOverride` does not add anything to `TestBase`, so the return value is just as per `TestBase` (but note that it is using the name passed into the constructor.

The most important lesson here is that YOU MUST provide an explicit return value if you expect to be able to assign (or log) the return value from a function.  The exception to this is if the function is an arrow function with a simple statement as the function body, in which case the arrow function takes that value as the (implicit) return.

```js
class TestBase {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  status() {
    return "TestBase " + this.name
  }
}

class TestOverride extends TestBase {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }

  status() {
    return "TestOverride " + super.status();
  }
}

class TestNoOverride extends TestBase {
  constructor(name) {
    super(name);
  }
}

const a = new TestBase("A")
console.log(a.status())

const b = new TestOverride("B")
console.log(b.status())

const c = new TestNoOverride("C")
console.log(c.status())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are logging the value returned by `b.checkStatus()`, which is `undefined` as the function does not return a value. Most likely you do not want this return value to be logged.

```js
class Test {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  status() {
    console.log("test")
  }
}

class Test1 extends Test {
      constructor(name) {
        super(name);
  }
    checkStatus() {
        super.status();
    }
}

const b = new Test1("Test")
b.checkStatus()
```

Comment: Should I use `return super.status();` instead?

Comment: @squnk It will not work even if you return `super.status()`, you'll need to add a return value inside the status() method itself

Comment: @AdnaneAr, with return super.status() I am not getting any errors

Comment: It is not about getting an error! But when you use `console.log(b.checkStatus())` this will always log `undefined` for the same reason this answer gave!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this line:

```
console.log(b.checkStatus())
```

This runs `checkStatus()` in the `Test1` class, which runs `status()` in Test. Well, consider `status()`:

```
console.log("test")
```

Ok, "test" is printed to the console. Now, as there is no return function, `undefined` is implicitly returned. `checkStatus()` therefore returns this value, `undefined`. You then log this with `console.log(b.checkStatus())`, printing `undefined`.

If you look carefully, you have two `console.log()`s in your program. Hence the two outputs, the second being `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your `checkStatus` method does not return anything.

It's the same as if you were doing

```js
function hello(){
  console.log('hello')
}

console.log(hello())
```

If you want your function to return something you can return something in the parent method and in the `checkStatus` method

```js
class Test {
    constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  
  status() {
    return "test"
  }
}

class Test1 extends Test {
      constructor(name) {
        super(name);
  }
    checkStatus() {
        return super.status();
    }
}

const b = new Test1("Test")
console.log(b.checkStatus())
```